# Cannot get file system ARN in cloud formation output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs, aws-cdk

I am trying to add cloud formation output for outputting ARN for EFS. I am using attribute 'file_system_arn' as mentioned in AWS docs

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_efs/FileSystem.html#aws_cdk.aws_efs.FileSystem.file_system_arn

However, when running it errors out -
AttributeError: 'FileSystem' object has no attribute 'file_system_arn'

I am completely baffled by this. Does anyone have any idea what might be going wrong?

Below is the code

```
from aws_cdk.aws_efs import FileSystem
from aws_cdk.core import CfnOutput

fs = FileSystem(
            scope=self,
            id="id",
            file_system_name="file system name",
            removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
            security_group=sg,
            vpc=vpc,
            encrypted=True,
            vpc_subnets=SubnetSelection(
                subnet_type=SubnetType.ISOLATED
            )
        )
        
CfnOutput(
            scope=self,
            id="cfnid",
            value=fs.file_system_arn,
            export_name="export name",
            description="ARN of the file system"
        )
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That was me being stupid. I was using older version of python module which did not support this attribute.